# Does Github Project Classic not exist anymore?

Tags: github

In my previous Github repos, I was able to create a project under the repo which was specific to the repo, but now I cannot see this option for the new repos.
I can still use Project (Classic) in my previous repos.

Github now push me to create a project under my account, and link to the repo, but I want to create a project just under the repo.
In my side, the problem is that, when I try to create an "Issue", the user can see all of my projects under my account, but I don't want that.
The user should only see the related project.

Can I somehow have the previous version of the projects?

Thanks

Comment: I have also the same wish and not have not yet found the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to find a solution related to this that is working now, I don't know if is the ideal one, but it seems there is a solution.

Follow this steps:
https://docs.github.com/en/issues/organizing-your-work-with-project-boards/managing-project-boards/copying-a-project-board

The solution is to go to a repo where you have a classic project and add one. After go yo menu, go to dots and copy. From there you can select the name and the repo where you wants to be add it.
After the new classic project is added to the new repo!
Hope it helps!